# Google play Service error in Unity IOS

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I have been added google play service in unity and its running fine on android ,But when i try to run it on IOS it gives linker error.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

iOS uses Game Center (if I'm correct) and Android uses Google Play.

That just might be the issue.